# "Binding<String> action tried to update multiple times per frame" on TextField with CurrentValueSubject binding

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I've been trying to find a good way to connect a `TextField` with a viewmodel, so that the inputs to the `TextField` don't immediately update the view.

Here is a working example:

```swift
struct TextFieldSamples: View {
    @StateObject var vm = TFViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        print(Self._printChanges())
        return VStack {
            TextField("placeholder",
                      text: Binding(
                        get: { vm.outputText },
                        set: { vm.subject.value = $0 }
                      ))
            Text(vm.outputText) // this will only update when the textfield holds >5 characters
        }
    }
}

class TFViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var outputText: String = ""
    let subject = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")

    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        subject
            .filter({ $0.count > 5 })
            .sink { self.outputText = $0 }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

However, I came across the propertyWrapped `CurrentValueSubject` below on the swiftbysundell.com blog

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Input<Value> {
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { subject.value }
        set { subject.send(newValue) }
    }

    var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
        subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private let subject: CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>

    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        subject = CurrentValueSubject(wrappedValue)
    }
}
```

Trying to use it, will result in the error `Binding<String> action tried to update multiple times per frame`.
(Not only that, the input behavior of the `TextField` gets messed up. This shows especially with Japanese input where the character transformations don't are not working most of the time.)

Here's a example showing this behavior:

```swift
struct TextFieldSamples: View {
    @StateObject var vm = TFViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        print(Self._printChanges())
        return VStack {
            TextField("placeholder", text: $vm.inputText)
            Text(vm.outputText)
        }
    }
}

class TFViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Input var inputText: String = ""
    @Published var outputText: String = ""

    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $inputText
            .filter({ $0.count > 5 })
            .sink { self.outputText = $0 }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand why the PropertyWrapper version is not working as expected.

Comment: Have you tried to `.debounce(for:)`? It may be enough to keep the rate below the threshold that caused the error.

Comment: Thank you @Yrb, I've tried that. The `Binding<String>` message still shows.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to a combination of the binding to the `inputText` field of  `vm` and the binding to the `vm` itself as a `@StateObject`.

When text is entered, It sends the value to the `inputText` binding. This allows the system to flag that the `TextField` needs to be re-evaluated.

But `inputText` is a struct property of the `vm` object.  Because `vm` is a `@StateObject` when inputText changes, the `vm` object broadcasts that the `TextFieldSamples` view needs to be re-evaluated. As part of that it also tries to set the value of `textInput` (to the value it already holds) which causes the "binding fired multiple times in the same frame" message.

You can eliminate the extra time the Binding fires by making `vm` a `@State` property instead of `@StateObject`.  Now the change to `inputText` will fire once, and `vm` will not broadcast the object change message that tries to fire it the second time.

**However**, when you do that the system won't know `TextFieldSamples` needs to be reevaluated so it will never see the change to `outputText`.

Comment: Very insightful and also very complicated. Are there any rules of thumb for preventing these warnings? Patterns that can make it easier to spot?

Comment: In this case the `inputText` has two mechanisms by which it can report its status.  One by virtue of being in an `ObervableObject` and the second as a publisher in the `@Input` property wrapper.  I think the pattern would be "pick one notification mechanism and stick to it".